# Compute $\varphi (180)$ where $\varphi$ is the Euler totient fuction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, totient-function

So I was given this question. Compute $\varphi (180)$ where $\varphi$ is the Euler totient fuction.

Here is my attempted solution:

$\varphi (180) = ?$ $m = 180 = 2^2 \cdot 5 \cdot 9$, $p_1 = 2, p_2 = 5, p_3 = 9, n = 5$

$\varphi (180) =  \sum_{k=0}^5 (-1)^k = \frac{(180)}{i\varepsilon S\prod P_i}  = \frac{(180)}{1} - \frac{(180)}{p_1} - \frac{(180)}{P_2} - \frac{(180)}{P_3} + \frac{(180)}{P_1P_2} + \frac{(180)}{P_1P_3} + \frac{(180)}{P_2P_3} - \frac{(180)}{P_1P_2P_3} $

This is all i really know, basically the general process on how to start the problem off but I get confused on how to go about it with subsets, etc.

Comment: Use multiplicativity, the answer is $\varphi(2^2)\varphi(5)\varphi(3^2)$. Each term is easily computed.  Inclusion/Exclusion will also do the job but it is more work.

Comment: @AndréNicolas can you kind of explain the process like how to set up the question to answer it. Like first p1 is this,.... then the subset is this....

Comment: Anyway, $9=3^2$ is not prime.

Comment: @AndréNicolas so would it be $\varphi (180) = \varphi (2^2 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5) = 180 - (1 - 1/2)( 1 - 1/3)(1 - 1/5) = 180 \cdot 1/2 /cdot 2/3 \cdot 4/5 = 48$?

Comment: I don't like fractions. It is $(2)(3\cdot 2)(4)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use co-prime multiplicativity, i.e. the property that $\varphi(pq) = \varphi(p)\varphi(q)$ when $(p, q) = 1$ to break it into individual prime factors.

It should then be easy to calculate each individual $\varphi(p^k)$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\phi (n)=n×(1-1/p_1)(1-1/p_2)..... (1-1/p_k)$$
Where $n=(p_1)^{n_1}(p_2)^{n_2} (p_3)^{n_3}....(p_k)^{n_k}$.

Comment: so would it be $\varphi (180) = \varphi (2^2 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5) = 180 - (1 - 1/2)( 1 - 1/3)(1 - 1/5) = 180 \cdot 1/2 /cdot 2/3 \cdot 4/5 = 48$

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your solution is that you are not removing the numbers having $GCD$ other that $2,5,9$ with $180$. Proceeding with your method, you should take into account every divisor of $180$ and then apply the same procedure. This will give you the correct answer.

Also it can be solved by using [multiplicativity of totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#1.29_The_function_.CF.86.28n.29_is_multiplicative).

Comment: so would it be $\varphi (180) = \varphi (2^2 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5) = 180 - (1 - 1/2)( 1 - 1/3)(1 - 1/5) = 180 \cdot 1/2  /cdot  2/3 \cdot 4/5 = 48$

Comment: $180*(1−1/2)(1−1/3)(1−1/5)$